# Change Icon and Title in Xamarin.Forms MasterDetail header in VS17?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So no matter what I do I can't set the icon or Title in the Bar Header of a MasterDetail page:

[image]

As you can see here, the standard @drawable/icon.png is shown. But I need it to be different than the application icon.
And there's no Title on the right of the icon.

No matter, what I try, I can't alter these two. (The hamburger Icon is changable though)

I have tried these on the MasterDetailPage page:

```
Title = "something";
Master.Title = "something";
Detail.Title = "something";

Icon = "something.png";
Master.Icon = "something.png";
Detail.Icon = "something.png";

BackgroundImage = "something.png";
Master.BackgroundImage = "something.png";
Detail.BackgroundImage = "something.png";
```

The Mainpage (inherits from MasterDetailPage) looks like:

```
public class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public SharedNaviPages.MasterPage masterPage;

    public MainPage()
    {
        masterPage = new SharedNaviPages.MasterPage();
        Master = masterPage;

        if (App.IsUserLoggedIn)
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new Views.CompanyPages.BookingPage());
        } else
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new SharedNaviPages.LoginPage());
        }

        masterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP)
        {
            MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;
        }
    }
```

My MainPage.cs simply organizes the Master and Detail page.
The Booking page has a .Xaml view and a codebehind file.

BookingPage.xaml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="HoldbarVikar.Views.CompanyPages.BookingPage"
             Title="Bookinger">
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="Bookings data goes here" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

BookingPage.xaml.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HoldbarVikar.Views.CompanyPages
{
public partial class BookingPage : ContentPage
{
    public BookingPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you use code-behind for your UI or XAML? please provide more codes for the page implementation.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I've added the relevant code. For the views am I using .xaml files and codebehind .xaml.cs files. I followed the MasterDetail Xamarin.Forms sample.

Comment: I too would like an answer to this question, I upgraded my libraries and now a plain-vanilla android icon is in the toolbar. Not sure where it even comes from, not an image file, possibly built into a library or perhaps downloaded at run time.