# Can I change the 3-bar-icon button of MasterDetail page?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to change the color of those 3 bars in the icon like is shown in the below image:

[image]

I have tried changing the `BarBackgroundColor`, `BarTextColor` & `Icon` attributes but nothing worked, below is the code for the MasterDetail xaml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MasterDetail_Test.Home"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MasterDetail_Test"
                  NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
                  NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <pages:HomeMaster x:Name="MasterPage" Icon="myIcon.png"/>
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage BarBackgroundColor="Red" BarTextColor="Green" Icon="myIcon.png">
      <x:Arguments>
        <pages:HomeDetail />
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

So what can do that?

Comment: you supply the icon, so you can edit the icon file to be whatever color you want

Comment: I have already tried please view the edit.

Comment: the Icon goes on the master page

Comment: I've also tried that but didn't work too, I'm also wondering where is the event that handles the click on that button and open the master list?

Comment: You can refer to this discussion (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239518/change-icon-and-title-in-xamarin-forms-masterdetail-header-in-vs17?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your HomeMaster inside a NavigationPage for the Master page and set the icon on that NavigationPage, like what you're doing for the Detail.

I'm using an MVVM framework which is doing some of this for me but I think that would do it for you. It looks like in addition I am setting the Master.Icon but you're already doing that.